# FormData can't into the Server, what problem in my Code

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

---

What can I do to send **FormData** to my *server*, my file is always null in server or return Unsupported  Media status 415, I try to solve the problem but have no idea now....

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="add_data" id="add_data" method="post" onsubmit="return false"   >
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" value="" id="files" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload">
    <br />
</form>
```

---

this my html part and then 
ajax

```
$('#add_data').submit(function () {
            var totalFiles; 
            totalFiles = document.getElementById("files").files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", totalFiles);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/food/addfile",
                type: "Post",
                data:myData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                },
                data:  totalFiles ,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    alert("success")
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                       return alert("請先執行前置作業");
                    }
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

---

and Controller

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost,Route("addfile")]
    public  IActionResult GetPicture(/*HttpPostedFileBase[] files*/)
    {
        #region test1
        //if (files != null)
        //{

        //    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        //    {
        //        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/"), file.FileName));
        //    }
        //}
        #endregion

        #region test2

        var req = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (req.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in req.Files.Keys)
            {
                var file = req.Files["files"];
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/"), file.FileName));
            }
        }


        #endregion

        return Json(new { Status = 1 > 0 ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILS" });
```

---

that all Code , please who can tell me thanks.

Comment: can you please add the result you got while running your code ?
are you getting 401 code error or 500 or even 404 , i cant tell , add more result

Comment: I running my code, it's answer 415 or into server return file  null, can't running

Comment: did you try to remvve the parames "files" ?

Comment: Submit  file as multipart/form-data withe [FromForm] instead or  neglect the attribute altogether parames